# WASAPI, Delays on m_AudioClient->Start()

Tags: c++, windows, audio, audio-streaming, wasapi

The app captures sound from a microphone using WASAPI.

This code initializes `m_AudioClient` that is of type `IAudioClient*`.

```
const LONG CAPTURE_CLIENT_LATENCY = 50 * 10000;
DWORD loopFlag = m_IsLoopback ? AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK : 0;
hr = m_AudioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED
    , AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_EVENTCALLBACK | AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_NOPERSIST | loopFlag
    , CAPTURE_CLIENT_LATENCY, 0, m_WaveFormat->GetRawFormat(), NULL);
```

Then I use `m_AudioClient->Start()` and `m_AudioClient->Stop()` to pause or resume capturing.

Usaually `m_AudioClient->Start()` takes `5-6` ms, but sometimes it takes about `150 ms`which is too much for the application.

If I once call `m_AudioClient->Start()` then subsecuent calls of `m_AudioClient->Start()` during next `5` seconds will be fast but after about `10-15` seconds next call of `m_AudioClient->Start()` will take logner (`150 ms`). So looks like it keeps some state several seconds and after that it needs to get to that state again which takes some time.

On another machine this delays never happen, every call of `m_AudioClient->Start()` takes about `30 ms`

On the third machine average duration of `m_AudioClient->Start()` is `140 ms` but peak values are about `1 s`.

I run the same code on all 3 machines. The michrophone is not exatly the same on most cases it is `Microphone Array Realtek High Definition Audio`.

Can somebody explain why these peak values for the duration `m_AudioClient->Start()` happen and how I can fix it?

Comment: Post this question on the appropriate Windows support forum.  There's a guy there called Matthew van Eerde who will likely answer this.

Comment: Not sure if it is the right place but I asked it here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/wasapi-delays-on-maudioclient-start/ac25153f-698f-4c4c-b34f-cb5615412497

Comment: Worth a shot.  I'll see if I can find somewhere better targeted.

Comment: Hokay, last time I had an audio-related question I posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/WINDOWS (and I did get a reply from Matthew).  But that was a while ago now, so YMMV, as they say.  Oh, and you might need an MSDN membership to post there, I'm not actually sure.